# C Programming Compile Issue

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list

Hey guys I am preparing for a interview where most of the programming will be done in C. I decided to implement a Linked List class in C so as to understand how objects are really implemented in a lower level language that does not support an object oriented paradigm. I have run into some compile issues, so anyone who is familiar with C please help (I have never programmed in C). I have posted my code below as well as the compile error immediately after it.

```
//Creating a LinkedList in C
//with 3 basic operations
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct node {
   int data;
   node* next;
} List;

void insertEnd(List *node, int elem);
void PrintList(List *node);
/*void insertEnd(List *node, int elem);
void remove(List *node, int elem);*/

int main () {
    List *head = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    head->data = 0;
    head->next = NULL;
    insertEnd(head, 3);
    insertEnd(head, 4);
    PrintList(head);
}
void insertEnd(List *node, int elem) {
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    List *new_node = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    new_node->data = elem;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    node->next = new_node;
}

void PrintList(List *node) {
while (node) {
    printf ("%i ->", node->data);
    node = node->next;
}
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
bash-4.1$ gcc -o LinkedList LinkedList.c
LinkedList.c:6: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘node’
LinkedList.c: In function ‘main’:
LinkedList.c:15: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
LinkedList.c:17: error: ‘List’ has no member named ‘next’
LinkedList.c: In function ‘insertEnd’:
LinkedList.c:24: error: ‘List’ has no member named ‘next’
LinkedList.c:25: error: ‘List’ has no member named ‘next’
LinkedList.c:27: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
LinkedList.c:29: error: ‘List’ has no member named ‘next’
LinkedList.c:30: error: ‘List’ has no member named ‘next’
LinkedList.c: In function ‘PrintList’:
LinkedList.c:36: error: ‘List’ has no member named ‘next’
```

Comment: Take many days or weeks to learn C and practice it. Enable all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`). Also `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member `next` should be declared with `struct node *next` and you have to include `stdlib.h` which contains the declaration of `malloc`:

And you have to compile with `-Wall` flag until your program is free from bugs.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// ...

typedef struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
} List;

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
typedef struct node {
   int data;
   node* next;
} List;
```

to

```
typedef struct node {
   int data;
   struct node* next;
} List;
```